# Windows Server 2012 - How to get the username/password of an IP that is trying to connect using RDS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, windows-server-2012

I'm new to server admin, hence my apologies if this is a very basic question.

I was going through my server's event log when I noticed under 'Application and Service Logs > Microsoft > Windows > RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS' branch, a stream of warnings. Upon opening some warnings show the following message :

```
A connection from the client computer with an IP address of xx.xx.xx.xx failed because 
the user name or password is not correct.
```

This warning is appearing multiple times from various IP addresses that doesn't belong to any of our trusted remote sites. I've found 8-10 IPs already, mostly from European ISPs Sweden/Poland/Netherlands etc. I'm not sure if we are under some kind of attack. My questions are:

1. How can I find further information about this event and IP. I.e. what was the username/password combination used by the ip address shown in the event log.
2. The above mentioned event log shows logs from this morning only. How can I find older logs under the same branch?

Answer (score 1):

You can't find the username and password - all that is stored is success or failure.

If you have RDP open to the internet, expect to see a LOT of these.  The bad guys are constantly scanning for and hammering away at such servers.  Eventually one of them might get lucky and guess someone's password.

To see all of them, filter by the event id of the records you are interested in.  Most of the logs only store a certain size before they start deleting old records, so it may not go back very far.